# Can someone help me with this algorithm?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, object

I want to take the following object and create an array of the following result. Best possible time complexity as well as use of lodash or any other libraries to make it a much more readable code.

```
var calendar = {
Q1 : {
    P1 : {
        WK1 : {
            start: '1/1/2018',
            end: '1/7/2018'
        },
        WK2 : {
            start: '1/8/2018',
            end: '1/14/2018'
        }
    },
    P2 : {
        WK3 : {
            start: '1/15/2018',
            end: '1/21/2018'
        }
    }
},
Q2 : {
    P3 : {
        WK5 : {
            start: '2/1/2018',
            end: '2/7/2018'
        },
        WK6 : {
            start: '2/8/2018',
            end: '2/14/2018'
        }
    },
    P4 : {
        WK7 : {
            start: '2/15/2018',
            end: '2/21/2018'
        }
    }
}
}
```

result is to be an array of objects where each object in the array will have the start date of the first week of it's period and the end date of the last week within its period like so:

```
[
    {
        quarter: 'Q1',
        period: 'P1',
        start_date: '1/1/2018',
        end_date: '1/14/2018'
    },
    {
        quarter: 'Q1',
        period: 'P2',
        start_date: '1/15/2018',
        end_date: '1/21/2018'
    },
        {
        quarter: 'Q2',
        period: 'P3',
        start_date: '2/1/2018',
        end_date: '2/14/2018'
    },
        {
        quarter: 'Q2',
        period: 'P4',
        start_date: '2/15/2018',
        end_date: '2/21/2018'
    }
]
```

Comment: show your code so far

Comment: StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [mcve]. For further information, please see [ask], and take the [tour] :) For this problem, you just need to use nested loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `reduce` for this kind of thing, here is an example:

```js
var calendar = {Q1 : {P1 : {WK1 : {start: '1/1/2018',end: '1/7/2018'},WK2 : {start: '1/8/2018',end: '1/14/2018'}},P2 : {WK3 : {start: '1/15/2018',end: '1/21/2018'}}},Q2 : {P3 : {WK5 : {start: '2/1/2018',end: '2/7/2018'},WK6 : {start: '2/8/2018',end: '2/14/2018'}},P4 : {WK7 : {start: '2/15/2018',end: '2/21/2018'}}}};

var result = Object.keys(calendar).reduce((a, c) => {
  Object.keys(calendar[c]).forEach(period => {
     let weeks = Object.values(calendar[c][period]);
     let firstWeek = weeks[0];
     let lastWeek = weeks[weeks.length - 1];
     a.push({quarter: c, period: period, start_date: firstWeek.start, end_date: lastWeek.end});
  });
  return a;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Please don't answer badly asked questions. This one is basically just asking for free code, with no attempt at a solution.